# run “term” on MS-Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, term

I typed `M-x term`; then Emacs prompted a query string followed by a default pathname:

```
Run program: D:/Progs/emacs-29.1/libexec/emacs/29.1/x86_64-w64-mingw32/cmdproxy.exe
```

Directly typed `<return>`.

Emacs emitted the following error message:

> start-process: Spawning child process: Invalid argument

---

Any way to run the command `term` on MS-Windows?